# Data science master thesis in robotics

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, sensors

I am writing my data science master thesis on "Decision making with sensor fusion and machine learning in unmanned systems"

What are the sub topics similar to "Collusion avoidance", "Navigation" and "Object Detection"? Are there publications about using big data in robotic systems, apart from these three?

Comment: Possibly you mean "Collision avoidance"?

Comment: You might want to check in on "inverse kinematics".  These problems are often solved with machine learning type models.

Comment: Scott thank you very much. You are the first person to give me an idea :) Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes. I meant Collision avoidance :)

Comment: Inverse kinematics can be an option. What else can be done when I have accelenometer, angular velocity, orientation, sonar and lidar data and video from a uav or a land vehicle? To predict the next state about what the vehicle will have to decide next?